# Is there a convenient way write sums and products with filters?

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, filters, nets

If we want to iterate a commutative and associative law of composition over $\{a_i\}_{i \in I}$ in some topological space for an index set $I$, there is a simple way to do it using the directed set of finite subsets $F \subset I$. The composition over $I$ can then be written as the limit over the net $\prod_{u \in F} a_i$ if it exists:

$$\prod_{i\in I} a_i := \lim_{F\subset I} \prod_{i \in F} a_i$$

In the countable sum case (over $\mathbb C$) this is different from a normal series in that it converges iff the series converges absolutely.

The construction allows you to consider uncountable sums and products: An example of an uncountable sum would be in the strong operator topology of a non-seperable Hilbertspace, if we have mutually orthogonal projections $\pi_i$ indexed by $\mathbb R$ with joint kernel $\{0\}$, then $\sum_{i \in \mathbb R} \pi_i =\mathbb 1$ in this topology.

Is there a similarly convenient way to get limits of sums and products using filters instead of nets?

Comment: Note: That summability is equivalent to absolute convergence for countable sums holds in finite-dimensional spaces, not in general. In $\ell^2(\mathbb{N})$, the family $\bigl\{ \frac{1}{n+1}\cdot e_n : n \in \mathbb{N}\bigr\}$ is summable, but not absolutely summable. In incomplete normed spaces, a (countable) family can be absolutely summable without being summable.

Comment: @DanielFischer I was thinking in that specific case about sums in $\mathbb C$ or $\mathbb R$. I did not know that in $\mathscr l^p$ spaces there was a notion of absolutely summable, though.

Comment: In a normed space, a family $\{ a_i : i \in I\}$ is absolutely summable if $\sum_{i\in I} \lVert a_i\rVert < +\infty$.

Comment: Anyway, while one can of course formulate these concepts in terms of filters, I'm not aware of a formulation that is as natural and direct as the formulation in terms of nets.