# Real Analysis, Folland problem 5.5.65 Hilbert Spaces

Tags: functional-analysis

> problem 5.5.65 - $l^2(A)$ is unitarily isomorphic to $l^2(B)$ if and only if $card(A) = card(B)$

Background Information: If $\mathcal{H}_1$ and $\mathcal{H_2}$ are Hilbert spaces with inner products $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle_1$ and $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle_2$, a unitary map from $\mathcal{H}_1$ to $\mathcal{H_2}$ is an invertible linear map $U:\mathcal{H}_1\rightarrow \mathcal{H}_2$ that preserves inner products $$\langle Ux, Uy\rangle = \langle x, y \rangle, \ \forall x\in\mathcal{H}_1$$
By taking $y = x$, we see that every unitary map is an isometry:$$\lVert Ux\rVert_2 = \|x\|_1$$

I am not really sure how to start with this proof, any suggestions is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does it mean for two sets to have the same cardinality, and what do elements of $\mathscr l^2 (A)$ and $\mathscr l^2(B)$ look like? Can you see any way to get a map from one to the other if $A$ and $B$ have the same cardinality?

Comment: That there exists a bijective mapping between them. Not sure about your other questions

Comment: What is the definition of $\mathscr l^2(A)$?

Comment: $l^2(A)$ is the set of functions $f: A\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ such that the sum $\sum_{\alpha\in A}|f(\alpha)|^2$ is finite.

Comment: If you have a function $g: B \to A$. Can you see why $\tilde g: \to \mathscr l^2(B)$ defined by $f \mapsto \tilde g(f) = f \circ g$ is well defined? (ie the image of $\mathscr l^2(A)$ does lie in $\mathscr l^2(B)$.)

Comment: no, not at first glance

Comment: Sorry I messed up the formatting. And I made a mistake, it has to be a bijection not just any function. At any rate if $\sum_{\alpha \in A}|f(\alpha)|^2$ is finite, then $\sum_{\beta \in B}|f(g(\beta)|^2$ is actually the same as $\sum_{\alpha \in A}|f(\alpha)|^2$. To see this look at the definition of a sum over a general set (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1692934/is-there-a-convenient-way-write-sums-and-products-with-filters ) and note that $g$ is a "re-ordering" of $B$ into $A$.

Comment: Ok, I see that now. I have to prove the sums are the same which would only work if the cardinality of $A$ and $B$ are the same?

Comment: You are reduced to showing that if $\{e_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha\in\Lambda}$ and $\{f_{\gamma}\}_{\gamma\in\Gamma}$ are complete orthonormal subsets of a Hilbert space $X$, then $\Lambda$ and $\Gamma$ have the same cardinality. This typically requires knowing that $A$ and $A\times A$ have the same cardinality for infinite $A$.

Comment: If anyone has a proof of this please provide I am still lost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A$ be a set. The definition of $\mathscr l^2(A)$ is as the set of functions $f: A \to \mathbb C$ that are square summable, ie for which $\sum_{\alpha \in A} |f(\alpha)|^2 < \infty$ holds. One consequence of this is that $f$ can be non-zero only on a countable subset of $A$. The space naturally has the structure of a vector space and it also has an inner product:

$$\langle g,f \rangle := \sum_{\alpha \in A} \overline{g(\alpha)}\ f(\alpha)$$

Before continuing note that a way of writing elements as $f \equiv \sum_{\alpha \in A} f(\alpha)\ e_\alpha$ where $\{e_\alpha\}_{\alpha \in A}$ is an orthonormal basis may be a more familiar way of looking at the space.

If two sets $A, B$ have same cardinality then there exists a bijection $F: B \to A$ between them. This induces a map $F_*: \mathscr l^2(A) \to \mathscr l^2(B)$ via $F_*(f):=f\circ F$. Since $F$ is a bijection it is equivalent for $\sum_{\alpha \in A} |f(\alpha)|^2$ to be finite and for $\sum_{\beta \in B} |(f\circ F)(\beta)|^2$ to be finite.

So $F_*$ is actually well defined, furthermore $(F^{-1})_*:\mathscr l^2(B) \to \mathscr l^2(A)$ is the same as $(F_*)^{-1}$ as can easily be verified.

It is also easy to see that $F_*$ (and its inverse) are linear maps. It remains to show unitarity. First do this in an unrigorous manner:

$$\langle g,f\rangle_{\mathscr l^2(A)}=\sum_{\alpha \in A}\overline{g(\alpha)}\ f(\alpha)\overset{(*)}{=}\sum_{\beta \in B}\overline{g( F (\beta ) )}\ f(F(\beta))=\langle F_* (g), F_*(f)\rangle_{\mathscr l^2(B)}$$

Where $(*)$ holds because $F$ essentially just rearranges the terms of an absolutely converging sum, renaming the index set from $A$ to $B$. To do this part more cleanly note that the essential step is to show that if we have an absolutely summable expression $\sum_{\alpha \in A}E(\alpha)$, then $\sum_{\beta \in B} E(F(\beta))$ is also absolutely summable and evaluates to the same thing ($E(\alpha) \in \mathbb C$).

Note that $\mathcal A \subset A$ is a finite set iff $F(\mathcal A)=\mathcal B$ for some finite set $\mathcal B \subset B$ ($F$ is bijection), and for finite sets we have equality:

$$\sum_{\alpha \in \mathcal A} E(\alpha)=\sum_{\beta \in F(\mathcal A)}E(F(\beta))$$

But the definition of a sum over a general infinite set is given by

$$\sum_{\alpha \in A} E(\alpha)=\lim_{\mathcal A \to A}\sum_{\alpha \in \mathcal A}E(\alpha) = \lim_{\mathcal A \to A}\sum_{\beta \in F(\mathcal A)}E(F(\beta))=\lim_{\mathcal B \to B}\sum_{\beta \in \mathcal B}E(F(\beta))$$

Where the limit $\mathcal A \to A$ is understood as the limit of the expression in the sense of nets. The last inequality follows from the identification of finite sets of $A$ with finite sets of $B$ via $F$ (note summable in this sense is the same as absolutely summable).

So the two spaces are indeed unitarily equivalent.